# Get which street im on using android LBS

Tags: java, android, location

I Would like to develop a simple android application that knows which street I am on approached from any direction. My question is how do you save all the co-ordinates/points  on which a certain street covers while saving power.Definitly the Libraries to use are the Location Manager, Location and LocationListner etc.

Would someone please give tips on what to do. Maps not.

Kind Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

> application that knows which street I am on

Using reverse geocoding you can get this address.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

It needs the internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanx Reno... and if i may ask what is <Address> is it an android Library? and what does it do?

Comment: It is the [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) class. Use getAddressLine() to get it in a String